# How to flip recorded video on x-axis using AVFoundation?

Tags: ios, objective-c, avfoundation

I am getting mirrored video after recording from front camera.

After recording done, I am getting output in method as mentioned below:-

```
- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureFileOutput *)captureOutput didFinishRecordingToOutputFileAtURL:(NSURL *)outputFileURL fromConnections:(NSArray *)connections error:(NSError *)error
```

How can I flip it on x-axis? So after saving, it should show properly as recorded.
Please help.

Answer (score 2):

Basically you have to setup a video output connection of the capture output during the capture session setup:

```
session.beginConfiguration()
//... Setup capture session    
if let videoOutputConnection = captureOutput?.connection(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo) {
    if videoOutputConnection.isVideoMirroringSupported == true {
        videoOutputConnection.automaticallyAdjustsVideoMirroring = false
        videoOutputConnection.isVideoMirrored = true
    }
}
session.commitConfiguration()
```

Answer (score 0):

try to set `automaticallyAdjustsVideoMirroring` of `AVCaptureConnection` to `NO`, or try to change `videoMirrored` property of `AVCaptureConnection`.

About videoMirrored property from docs

> A Boolean value that indicates whether the video flowing through the connection should be mirrored about its vertical axis.. This property is only applicable to connections involving video.
>   if the value of 
>   supportsVideoMirroring
>    is 
>   YES
>   , you can set videoMirrored to 
>   YES
>    to flip the video about its vertical axis and produce a mirror-image effect.

See [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcaptureconnection?language=objc) for more info.